# How do you set a length and justify an Array field in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, customization

I'm breaking down a text file, and setting it to a new one. The code works, but I know the format doesn't line up correctly, because i'm new to Perl-and a google search didn't seem to work. Can you set your array's individual field lengths once you've built the array?

```
while (my $line = <INFILE1>) 
{   
    chomp $line;
    my @tokens = split /\t/, $line;
    $numOfElements = 0;
    $counter = 0;
    foreach $element (@tokens)
    {
        $counter = $counter + 1;
    }

foreach $element (@tokens)
{

    if ($element eq "" or $element eq " ")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        push @shiftedElements, $element;

        $numOfElements = $numOfElements + 1;

    }



}


my @finalElementLine = ($numOfElements);#used to prevent array size` from not matching up with the elements in the new array
    push @finalElementLine, @shiftedElements;#fills the new array 
    $printToFile = " $finalElementLine[1] |   $finalElementLine[2]   |   $finalElementLine[$numOfElements]   |   $finalElementLine[$numOfElements-4]  |  $finalElementLine[$numOfElements-3] | $finalElementLine[$numOfElements-2]  $finalElementLine[$numOfElements-1]\n";




    my $OUTFILE;        
    open $OUTFILE, '>>', $newFile;
    print { $OUTFILE } $printToFile;
    close $OUTFILE;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the goal -- to line up the output?  What does this mean: "_prevent array size from not matching up with the elements in the new array_"?  Can you post the desired output, if that is the question?

Comment: The output needed to be seen when you open the .txt file. It has to line up with the columns which need to be a pre-deterimined length. The comment in the code was for the other programmer to know that each array of elements had a max length of elements, so we could reference later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I fully understand the question, please clarify if needed.

The width of a field that is being printed can be controlled by [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html), or you can form a string of the desired length by [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

For the whole output to line up nicely you'd first need to find the length of the longest string in each column, or at least the longest one altogether.  That is not quite possible in what you show since you print one line at a time.

```
my $maxlen = '...';  # decide on or precompute the maximum field width

my $printToFile = join ' |  ', 
    map { sprintf "%${maxlen}s", $_ } @finalElementLine;
```

The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) formats a string of length `$maxlen` out of each element, by padding each with spaces as needed. It returns that list, which is then [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)-ed into a scalar by what is used in the question.

If you want to line them up on the left use `sprintf "%-${maxlen}s", $_`. I use the `s` conversion (for a string) since no details are given.  See the documentation and adjust if needed.

In order to reliably estimate the maximum field width you'd need to have all lines first.  If there isn't too much data you can store each processed line as an arrayref in an array and print at the end. With other simplifications

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw(max);

my $file = '...';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{   
    chomp $line;
    my @tokens = split /\t/, $line;   

    # Run the explicit loop if other processing is needed, or:
    my @shiftedElements = grep { $_ ne '' and $_ ne ' ' } @tokens;
    my $numOfElements = @shiftedElements;

    # UNCLEAR -- is the first element below necessary?
    # "used to prevent array size from 
    #  not matching up with the elements in the new array"
    my @finalElementLine = ($numOfElements, @shiftedElements);

    push @rows, \@finalElementLine;
}
close $fh;

my $maxlen = max map { length } map { @$_ } @rows;  # for all fields in all rows

open my $OUTFILE, '>>', $newFile or die "Can't open for appending: $!";
foreach my $rline (@rows) 
{
    my $printToFile = join ' |  ', 
        map { sprintf "%${maxlen}", $_ } @$rline;
    print $OUTFILE $printToFile, "\n";
}
close $OUTFILE;
```

This prints out *all* fields with the same width. If some are much longer than others that isn't optimal, in which case set field widths separately for *each column* and use that in printing. That makes printing quite a bit messier so do it only if necessary. This has not been tested since I don't have your data, please work out possible details.

Some comments

- When an array is assigned to a scalar, the scalar gets the number of array elements
- `$counter` isn't used so I removed it. To restore: `my $counter = @tokens;`
- The condition in `grep` can be shortened using regex
- Each line (`@finalElementLine`) is stored in `@rows` as an arrayref
- `$maxlen`: form a list of all fields in all rows, then take their lengths, then take max of that
- Each element `$rline` of `@rows` is *dereferenced* by `@$rline` into a list for `map`
- If `$NumOfElements` actually isn't needed the whole loop simplifies greatly

  ```
  push @rows, [ grep { not /^(?:| )$/ } @tokens ];
  ```
- If you may exclude *any amount* of space (and not only a single one), then use
  `grep { not /^\s*$/ }`   *not* only spaces (or nothing)   – OR –
  `grep { /\S/ }`                 a non-space (at least one)

---

If `$numOfElements` isn't necessary, a summary of the processing sequence is

```
my @rows = map { 
    my @r = grep { /\S/ } split /\t/; 
    @r ? \@r : (); 
} <$fh>;
```

While this correctly replaces the `while` loop, such a squeeze is likely unsuitable for production.

The `<$fh>` in list context returns all lines from the file, which `map` transforms into an output list, assigned to `@rows`. In `map` each line is `split` on tab and from that list empty/space-only elements are filtered out. The refarray is returned, or an empty list `()` if `@r` ended up with no elements.

An empty list in `map`'s return gets flattened with other elements into one list and thus effectively vanishes from the output. It's `map`'s trick to do `grep`'s job, filter things out.

Comment: Thank you! The input comes in tab delimited, but needs to be lined up, re-arranged by a user, and printed to new file where everything lines up nice and neat. Thank you!